# Exclude certain pages from GA pageview report

Tags: google-analytics

I have a pageview report where I want to exclude certain urls to show from the report like /user/* , /admin/*, /404 etc. How to do this in the custom report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a filter by **regex** and **exclude** that pages with pipe separator, i.e.:

```
Exclude --> Page --> Regex --> \/user/\|\/admin\/|\/404
```